# Karate-Apache-HttpHostConnectException Upon Upgrading to Karate 1.4

Tags: java, http, karate

`Background:` My Karate test cases were running fine with Karate 0.9.6 version.
Currently I am trying to upgrade my Karate version to 1.4.0 and facing issues. Java version is 17.

`Solutions Tried:` Followed documentation [Karate-1.0-upgrade-guide](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/1.0-upgrade-guide) and removed karate-apache dependency in pom and updated Runner method. Added karate-core dependency in pom.

While running karate test cases facing below error:

`ERROR:` com.intuit.karate -- karate.org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to 127.0.0.1:8080 [/127.0.0.1] failed:
Connection refused: no further information, http call failed after 474 milliseconds for url: http://127.0.0.1:8080/

`karate-config.js`

```
function fn() {
var env = karate.env;
karate.configure('connectTimeout', 5000);
karate.configure('readTimeout', 8000);
var port = karate.properties['demo.server.port'];
var url = karate.properties['demo.server.url'];
if (!port) {
    port = karate.env == 'web' ? 8090 : 8080;
}
var protocol = 'http';
if (karate.properties['demo.server.https'] == 'true') {
    protocol = 'https';
    karate.configure('ssl', true);
}
env = 'test';
var config = {
   env: env,
   baseUrl: protocol + '://127.0.0.1:' + port,
   basePath: '/karateTesting/1.0',
   baseHeader: 'classpath:com/karate/headers/',
   baseReq: 'classpath:com/karate/requests/',
   baseResp: 'classpath:com/karate/responses/'
}
if (url) {
    config.baseUrl = url;
}
if (karate.env == 'proxy') {
    var proxyPort = karate.properties['demo.proxy.port'];
    karate.configure('proxy', 'http://127.0.0.1:' + proxyPort);
}
return config; }
```

`Runner Class`

```
@Test
void testParallel() {
    Results results = Runner.path("classpath:com/karate/test_api.feature").tags("~@ignore").parallel(5);
    generateReport(results.getReportDir());
    assertEquals(0, results.getFailCount(), results.getErrorMessages());
}
```

`POM.xml`

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
        <artifactId>karate-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0</version>
        <classifier>all</classifier>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I can't help unless you follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue - lets hope someone else has some ideas

Answer (score 0):

i got the same error when running my test in a docker container. adding the next line in feature file background solved my issue

```
*configure driver = { type: 'chrome', start: false, showDriverLog: true, host:'127.0.0.1' }
```